# How to make a discord bot use other discord bot commands?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

im creating a discord bot in python and i would like to make my bot command the music bot to play music. for example i want my bot to write /play prompet:[SONG_NAME] in a chat room and let it be recognized and played by the other music bot. if someone has an idea to make it work please help!

i been trying to just write a string with my own bot "/play prompet:[SONG_NAME]" but the other bot is not reacting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. Discord.py by default doesn't invoke commands on messages of other bots, unless you override `on_message` and call `process_commands` without checking the message author.

Consequently, if the bot is not yours and you cannot control it, there's nothing you can do about it. If the other bot allows it then it will work without you having to do anything.

Invoking slash commands from chat will never work, as they're not made to be called by bots.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer, after a little bit of testing i started to think if they could do that then bots may be exploited and spammed..

thank you!